# SQL Server - Select statement with multiple conditions from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to execute a SQL query in SSMS to return the row count for terminalID that exists in another table and also where the record is greater than 2015 but it throws me an error. Here is my query:

```
select count(*) 
from AuditTerminal(nolock)
where TerminalID in (Select TerminalID from Terminal)
  and (select * from Terminal where LastChangeDate >= '2015-01-01')
```

Is there any way to put the last line so the condition succeeds?

EDIT: what about this?

```
select * 
from AuditTerminal(nolock)
where TerminalID in (select TerminalID from Terminal)
  and exists (select * from Terminal where LastChangeDate >= '2015-01-01')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to do:

Since you are putting two conditions on same table, I assume that you need to find all terminals which exists in Terminal table after Jan 2015 01 and are also in AuditTerminal. So put them in single query.

```
select count(*) 
 from AuditTerminal(nolock)
        where TerminalID IN 
 (Select TerminalID from Terminal where  LastChangeDate>= '2015-01-01')
```

Also we can use JOINs which makes a little more sense(at least to me ;))

```
select count(*) 
from AuditTerminal (nolock) as A
INNER JOIN Terminal (nolock) as T
on T.TerminalID =A.TerminalID 
        AND   T.LastChangeDate>= '2015-01-01'
```

**And if you are looking for unique count please use
`count(DISTINCT TerminalID )` instead**

Comment: Is there other alternative without using join statement?

Comment: Okay I prefer to use your first method since it's less complicated :)

Comment: What do you mean, there are some TerminalID like 4 which have a few records in AuditTerminal. I want to know the TOTAL Records.

Comment: For your first solution, can I use: ( Select * FROM Terminal where lastchangedate........) ??? Will it return same?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **`EXISTS`**.

**Query**

```
select count([TerminalID]) as [TerminalID_count]
from [AuditTerminal] at
where exists(
    select 1 from [Terminal] t
    where at.[TerminalID] = t.[TerminalID]
    and t.[LastChangeDate] >= '2015-01-01'
);
```